# Application of Riemann roch-Calculation of index

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Sorry for an ambiguous title. Let me know if you can think of anything better please! Trying to figure out the reason for an equality from a paper.

Let $k$ be a function field over a finite field (namely a global function field) and let $A=\prod_PP^{v_P(A)}$ be a sufficiently large divisor of $k$ such that $\mathbb{A}_k=k+\prod_P{P}^{-v_P(A)}.$ (This is possible as Adeles over global field is compact.)

Then we are supposed to have $[k\cap \prod_P P^{-v_P(A)}:0]=$deg$(A)$ "by Riemann-Roch" which I don't quite see. I see that right hand side is precisely the dimension of Riemann-Roch space and I thought index of specialty has to be $0$ due to the specially chosen divisor $A$. This should give LHS=deg$(A)-g+1$ from my understanding but $g$ is not necessarily 1 (where $g$ is genus of $k$ over its constant field).

It might be the case that we could make sure that $k$ is a finite $p$-extension of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}(T)$ but even so I don't see how this could change anything.

For those who are interested what paper I am reading it's Class formation II by Kawada-Satake.

Comment: I have no idea why but someone posted exactly same question on overflow (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232290/application-of-riemann-roch-calculation-of-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as I have figured this out but what this question is asking is terribly wrong in many ways. The equality I have written down is not even close to correct and even after fixing that it's still incorrect. But the remaining bit is constant which cancels so the paper is still correct. The paper is very misleading though which is why I am rewriting the paper so that it's easier to read.